# How do I force a database flush when saving large amounts of data in Grails?

Tags: java, mysql, grails

I've created a Grails application that pulls a 300MB text file from Google Storage via http (a once off import). The text file contains 35 000 000 codes that need to be stored into a MySQL database.

I created a `Thread` that loops through the incoming `InputStream`, creates a list of domain objects, loads them into an `Array` and batch saves that array every 100 iterations.

The process would take hours to complete (which is okay). The issue is that when querying the table, I don't see a single record being saved. It's being buffered or cached somewhere, seemingly waiting for the process to complete - which is exactly what I don't want!

**Code snippet**

```
synchronized processImport (String url, String importType) throws RuntimeException {

    InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String code;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        List<ComingInHotCode> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
        while((code = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                buffer.add(new CodeDomainObject([code: code, used: false, type: importType]));
                if (i % 100 == 0) {
                    CodeDomainObject.saveAll(buffer);
                    buffer.clear();
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                println ("Save error:" + ex.getMessage())
            }
            i++;
        }
        CodeDomainObject.saveAll(buffer);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

**Note**

1. `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()` doesn't seem to do anything
2. `flush:true` doesn't seem to do anything
3. I've just implemented a custom Thread in a service to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

*Managed to solve the problem myself. For those interested*

Use a stateless hibernate session and start and commit the transactionsns manually:

```
synchronized processImport (String url, String importType) throws RuntimeException {

    InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String code;
    int i = 0;

    StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    def tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        List<ComingInHotCode> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
        while((code = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (i % 1000 == 0 && i > 0) { 
                // After every 1000 records commit and reopen a new.
                tx.commit();
                Thread.sleep(1000); // I just added this to give the GC a chance
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
            }

            session.insert(new MyDomainObject([code: code, used: false, type: importType]));

            i++;
        }

        tx.commit();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        stream.close();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `save( flush:[true/false] )` instead of those strange hand-made bufferings and tx-commits:

```
new URL(url).withReader{ reader ->
  MyDomainObject.withTransaction{
    int counter = 0
    reader.eachLine{ String line ->
      counter++
      new MyDomainObject( code:code ).save( flush:0 == counter % 1000 )
    }
  }
}
```

And yes, if your code is running in some other thread, it should be enclosed in `MyDomainObject.withTransaction{}`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to let the grails create and destroy sessions and transactions

```
synchronized processImport(String url, String importType) throws RuntimeException {

    InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String code;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        List<CodeDomainObject> buffer = []
        while ((code = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                buffer.add(new CodeDomainObject([code: code, used: false, type: importType]));
                if (i % 1000 == 0 && i > 0) {
                    flushBuffer(buffer)
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                println("Save error:" + ex.getMessage())
            }
            i++;
        }
        flushBuffer(buffer)

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        stream.close();
    }
}

private void flushBuffer(List<CodeDomainObject> buffer) {
    CodeDomainObject.withNewSession {
        CodeDomainObject.withNewTransaction {
            CodeDomainObject.saveAll(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```